# How to multiply var with var

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i want to use the person to multiply the fuel but it run out with NaN. How to solve it ?

```
fuel["fuel1"]=525*1*12*person();
```

```js
<script>
 var person = new Array();
 person["person1"]=1; // 1 person's trash produces 692 lbs of CO2 per year
 person["person2"]=2;
 person["person3"]=3;
 person["person4"]=4;

 var fuel= new Array(); // 100l produce 525lbs of CO2
 fuel["None"]=0;
 fuel["fuel1"]=525*1*12*person();
 fuel["fuel2"]=525*1.5*12;
 fuel["fuel3"]=525*2*12;
 fuel["fuel4"]=525*2.5*12;
 fuel["fuel5"]=525*3*12;
 fuel["fuel6"]=525*3.5*12;
 fuel["fuel7"]=525*4*12;
 fuel["fuel8"]=525*4.5*12;
 fuel["fuel9"]=525*5*12;
 fuel["fuel10"]=525*5.5*12;
 fuel["fuel11"]=525*6*12;
 fuel["fuel12"]=525*6.5*12;

function getNumberperson()
{  
    var numberperson=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var selectedPerson = theForm.elements["selectedperson"];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedPerson.length; i++)
    {
        if(selectedPerson[i].checked)
        {
            numberperson = person[selectedPerson[i].value];
        }
    }
    return numberperson;
}

function getFueltotal()
{
    var fueltotal=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
     var selectedFuel = theForm.elements["fuel"];     
    fueltotal = fuel[selectedFuel.value];
    return fueltotal;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var cakePrice = getNumberperson() + getFueltotal();
    
    //display the result

    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = +cakePrice;

}

//add a function to hide the result on page loading at the start
function hideTotal()
{
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "0";
} 


</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="wrap">
        <form action="/action_page.php" id="energyform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Carbon Footprint Calculator</legend>
                <label >Size Of Household</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4</label><br/>
<br/>
                <label >Household Fuel Consumption per month in liters</label>
         
                <select id="fuel" name='fuel' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="None">Select Fuel in liters</option>
                <option value="fuel1">100</option>
                <option value="fuel2">150</option>
                <option value="fuel3">200</option>
                <option value="fuel4">250</option>
                <option value="fuel5">300</option>
                <option value="fuel6">350</option>
                <option value="fuel7">400</option>
                <option value="fuel8">450</option>
                <option value="fuel9">500</option>
                <option value="fuel10">550</option>
                <option value="fuel11">600</option>
                <option value="fuel12">650</option>
               </select>
                <br/>
                <p>Total CO2 produced per year per household:</p>
                <div id="totalPrice">0</div>
                <div>US Household average is 21,820 lbs per year.
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            
            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
            <input type='reset' id='reset' value='Reset' onclick="hideTotal()" />
        </div>  
       </form>
                    </div>

</body>
              </html>
```

Comment: First of all you're using string keys on [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which, while it works, presents problems, you should instead be using [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Secondly `person` is an Array, so calling `person()` doesn't do anything (and should be throwing an error). Instead you need to access the relevant index of the array `525*1*12*person[0];` (though again you're using string keys which is odd to say the least so `525*1*12*person["person1"];`)

Comment: What do you think that `person()` should do? It’s not a function so you’re calling it in the wrong way, and you’re not supplying any arguments (or indices, or property-names) so it looks like you want to perform multiplication of an array object, which can’t do anything except result in an error or unexpected behaviour. So what’s the goal of the code you’ve written?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `* person();` from `fuel["fuel1"] = 525 * 1 * 12 * person();` that is causing error and interrupts code from assigning values to fuel.
Then instead of plus sign in `getNumberperson() + getFueltotal();`, use *.